# How I can open a door with animations?

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, scripting

I have this script:

```
Ray ray = new Ray (cam.transform.position, cam.transform.forward);
        RaycastHit hit;
        Debug.DrawRay (transform.position, ray.direction * 50f);
        if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.E)) {

            if (Physics.Raycast (ray, out hit, 50.0f)) {
                if (hit.collider.gameObject.tag == "Door") {

                    Debug.Log ("YEAH");
                }
            }
        }
```

How I can start animation open door?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that you need to know before you can animate that door.
There are multiple ways to animate an object in Unity. For simple things like that you could decide to just rotate the object (but you need to understand that you will need a Coroutine or a Mathf.MoveTowards or Mathf.Lerp method to avoid instant moving when you call everything in the Update).
But you can also use an animation made by someone else in applications like Blender.
Or finally create an animation with the Unity in game editor and create an Animator to animate your door.

I think that you should use this way.
First follow this official manual:
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/animeditor-CreatingANewAnimationClip.html

to create the clip to open your door.
It's really intuitive and you don't even need to code.

After that you should create an Animator Controller:
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-AnimatorController.html

You will than create a new state with your animation and you will create a connection between the initial state to your "Open door" animation.
After that you just create a simple bool (in your Animator Controller).

And you will add

this.GetComponent().SetBool("nameofyourboolintheanimatorcontroller", true);

to your script (of course this is valid only if your Animator Controller is in the object assigned to your script... if not you should create a new Animator variable and assign it (for example you could make it public and assign it in the editor).